# Change an object value inside a loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const data = [{
  _id:"49847444033",
  name:"yoko"
},{
  _id:"49847433333",
  name:"doira"
}]
```

I have to change each item name property to something like this :

```
...
{
  _id:"49847433333",
  name:{
      en:"John"
    }
}
```

My attempt is to loop object like following :

```
data.forEach((item) => {
   item.name = {en:"john"}
   console.log(item)
})
```

But this always console the original item and the name property value is not modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
const newData = data.map(user => ({ _id: user._id, name: { en: user.name } }))
```

Comment: Thank you, so when i have an object with 20 properties, i have to write down like this ? { _id: user._id, name: { en: user.name }, ..... } where .... is the others properties ?

Comment: yeah, just append them, though if you really have 20 props and want to copy all of them, just do `{...user, newProp: 'newValue'}`, (there 3 dots are part of the code)

Comment: Hi, your solution is working but when append like you said {..., newProp:"newValue"} output elements has new properties like : '$__': InternalCache {
      strictMode: true,
      selected: {},
      shardval: undefined,
     ....

Why?

Comment: const d = newData.map( (item) => {  return {...item, name:{en:"test"}} } )

Answer (score 0):

try somthing like:

```
const newList = data.map(obj => {
return { _id: obj._id, name: { en: obj.name } }
});
```

and the newList list is your new data list so you can do it:

```
data = newList;
```

EDIT:

if you have more properties you can change the return line to:

```
return { ...obj, name: { en: obj.name } }
```

what will happen here, it will deploy all the object properties as they are, and modify the name property, unfortunately, every property you want to modify, you have to re-write it.

Comment: Thank you, consider there is 20 properties, how to avoid to write them all?

Comment: @ikalangita its depends if you have to reformat them like "name" property.
if they have no change, you can change the return to:
return { ...obj, _id: obj._id, name: { en: obj.name } }, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I created a library to express transformations like this very simply.

```js
const { pipe, fork, get } = require('rubico')

const data = 
    [ { _id: '49847444033', name: 'yoko'} 
    , { _id: '49847433333', name: 'doira'} 
    ]

const onData = pipe([
  fork({
    _id: get('_id'), // data => data._id
    name: fork({ en: get('name') }), // data => ({ en: data.name })
  }),
  console.log,
])

data.map(onData) /*
{ _id: '49847444033', name: { en: 'yoko' } }
{ _id: '49847433333', name: { en: 'doira' } }
*/
```

I've commented the code above, but to really understand rubico and get started using it, I recommend you read the [intuition](https://github.rubico.land#introduction) and then the [docs](https://github.rubico.land#documentation)